# How do I change an image "B" by hovering over a linked image A without JavaScript only CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to change a picture "B" when I hover over a linked picture "A"

Similar to this [http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JsX8x/1](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JsX8x/1/)

```
    <div id="a">
    <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/nature" />
    <img class="first" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/people" />
    <img class="second" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/sports" />    
    </div>
```

but in this example I would like the first picture to also be linked to another page.

When I try to link this picture it breaks the picture change of image B

Any insight would be helpful

Clarification (from comment):

I would like to change one picture based on a variety of links.

the example page is here: http://mouco.com/testerre

I would like the super friends picture to change based on the link chosen.

Also having the link change too....

on the page the only link that has a rollover is the "history" link, but I would like all of them to change like this one, while changing the image on the side to a different image based on the link ...

Comment: I would like to change one picture based on a variety of links.

the example[link to example page][1] page is here: 
 
 


  [1]: http://mouco.com/testerre

I would like the super friends picture to change based on the link chosen.

Also having the link change too....

on the page the only link that has a rollover is the "history" link, but I would like all of them to change like this one, while changing the image on the side to a different image based on the link ...

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the image in an "a" tag and change styles accordingly.

HTML

```
<div id="a">
    <a href="google.com"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/nature" /></a>
    <a href="google.com" class="first"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/people" /></a>
    <img class="second" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/sports" />    
</div>
```

CSS

```
#a img.second,
#a a.first:hover ~ img.second {
    display: none;
}

#a a:hover ~ a.first {
    display: none;
}

#a a:hover ~ img.second {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

#### jsfiddle

Comment: I would like to change one picture based on a variety of links.

the example[link to example page][1] page is here: 
 
 


  [1]: http://mouco.com/testerre

I would like the super friends picture to change based on the link chosen.

Also having the link change too....

on the page the only link that has a rollover is the "history" link, but I would like all of them to change like this one, while changing the image on the side to a different image based on the link ...

Answer (score 0):

Add a hypertext reference link around the image you'd like to use

```
    <div id="a">
    <a href="www.website.com">**<img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/nature" /> </a>
    <img class="first" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/people" />
    <img class="second" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/400/sports" />    
    </div>
```